# HTML5 Canvas - Text ontop of rectangle

Tags: html, canvas

My code currently like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++)
{
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = '#d0d0d0';
        context.rect(data.data[i].x, data.data[i].y, 200, 25);
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';  
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.font = 'bold 20px serif';
        context.fillText("1212a", data.data[i].x, data.data[i].y + 20);         
}
```

Draws the rectnagle with the stroke but the text is beeing draw underneath the rectangle I tried changing the order of the code but still underneath...

Answer (score 0):

There there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. The problem might simply be a result of caching.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("main");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = 80;
var y = 50;

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = '#d0d0d0';
context.rect(x, y, 200, 25);
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';  
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.font = 'bold 20px serif';
context.fillText("1212a", x, y + 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="300px" height="100px">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine. You must have a problem somewhere else in your js file.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = '#d0d0d0';
context.rect(50, 50, 200, 25);
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';  
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.font = 'bold 20px serif';
context.fillText("1212a", 50, 50 + 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```